# Wildcard on key in graylog

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2, graylog

Hi I am trying to use wildcard on key inside of my query. Because I have arrays in my data so I am saving my data in flat form. Like obj_0_id, obj_1_ID and so on. So is there any way to write something like this obj_*_ID:123
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_multi_field) which lets you specify wildcards on field names. Example from docs:

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["city.*"],
        "query" : "this AND that OR thus",
        "use_dis_max" : true
    }
}
```